# Angular - img load fine locally, but not on development server

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I have this `<img>` which loads an image from the `planeringskartaSrc` variable, which works fine when the `arrayBuffer` image is passed as an input for the function `arrayBufferToBase64` in my local environment. It also works fine to load the default image `planeringskarta_notfound.png` when the `buffer` to the function is null when I run the application on `localhost`. When I deploy the application to the development server the arrayBuffer image is passed as an input to the function loads which works just fine, but `/assets/img/planeringskarta_notfound.png` could not load in the application. For the project I have linked the `assets` folder like this in the `angular.json` file:

**angular.json:**

```
"assets": [
              "projects/up-client/src/assets",
              "projects/up-client/src/assets/icons/favicon.ico"
            ],
```

**HTML:**

```
<img (click)="previewPlaneringskarta()" class="planeringskarta" [src]="planeringskartaSrc"/>
```

**TypeScript:**

```
arrayBufferToBase64( buffer ) {
    let binary = '';
    const bytes = new Uint8Array( buffer );
    const len = bytes.byteLength;

    if (!buffer) {
      return this.planeringskartaSrc = "/assets/img/planeringskarta_notfound.png";
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
      binary += String.fromCharCode( bytes[ i ] );
    }

    const imageSrc = 'data:image/gif;base64,' + window.btoa( binary );
    this.planeringskartaSrc =  this.sanitization.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(imageSrc);
  }
```

Why does the image load locally but not on development server?

Comment: Is the image accessible "manually" (i.e. by navigating directly to the www.your.dev.hosting.com/assets/img/planeringskarta_notfound.png? Is the base-href set correctly for that environment?

Comment: I have this img which works fine in the development server in the project which also starts the src path from assets folder: `icons: {
        filter: '<img src="assets/icons/filter.svg"  alt="filter"/>',
        sortUnSort: '<span></span>,
      },` So the base-href should be right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try removing slash at the start of src path like this "assets/img/planeringskarta_notfound.png"

Comment: I knew it was something litle that I missed thank you!